# How to parse query string in bash into if then statement

Tags: bash, rsync

How can I use bash to scan for a specific string of characters in a text file and then use an if then statement to execute a specific command depending on the string?
I am trying to use rsync to back up some raspberry pis from a query string output from an HTML form. I have minimal bash experience and I have been poking and prodding this code for days now and I would love for some advice.

QUERY_STRING will contain something similar to "Backup_To_Comp=tasting-side_backup&subbtn=Submit" with the "Tasting-side_backup" being swapped for other radial button tags as selected.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""


echo "$QUERY_STRING" > /var/www/cgi-bin/scan.txt

BackupToCompFrom=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*Backup_To_Comp=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`

echo "<html><head><title>What You Said</title></head>"

echo "<body>Here's what you said:"
echo "You entered $BackupToCompFrom in from field."

sleep 1

file="/var/www/cgi-bin/scan.txt"
##echo "$QUERY_STRING"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
    if [[ $line = "tasting-side_backup" ]]; then
    echo "GotIt."
      rsync pi@192.168.1.1:/home/pi/screenly_assets /home/pi/Downloads  
    elif [[ $line = "~tasting-main"* ]]; then
      print "Tasting Main" 
    elif [[ $line = "~lodge"* ]]; then
      print "Lodge" 
    elif [[ $line = "~barn"* ]]; then
      print "Barn" 
        else
      print "Please select a pi to copy from!"
    fi

done
```

Comment: There is crucial info missing here: 1) What is your question? 2) What is the value of `$QUERY_STRING`? 3) What input does this script receive, via stdin? You can [edit] to add the missing info, but a [MCVE] would be much better.

Comment: Where do you actually use `$BackupToCompFrom` (besides `echo`)?

Comment: I apologize I used that to name the inputs for the html form that the query string outputs. The echo is just so whoever is using the code gets a confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use bash to scan for a specific string of characters in a text file and then use an if then statement to execute a specific command depending on the string?

You can use a command in the if statement. Now the exit code for that command is used to determine true or false. For simple searching of a query to a file, you can use grep.

```
if grep -q "$QUERY_STRING" file; then
```

The -q is used to prevent any output from grep ending up in stdin.

Comment: Thanks this worked, honestly I have used grep before and I don't know why I didn't think about it here. I was so focused on forcing while read line to work I got stuck I guess. Thanks again.